# How to uninstall corrupt pip

Tags: python, pip

I did a pip operation and got a suggestion from pip to upgrade:

> You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
>
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Unfortunately I upgraded using sudo, even though I'm not convinced it is what actually caused my problems: `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Now whatever I try, pip complains about me not using pip 9.0.1:

```
pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 657, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 670, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I want to either downgrade or reinstall, but all suggestions I find suggest doing `pip uninstall pip` or similar and that is not really an option at this point.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider having a look at the permissions defined for `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pip`. Probably this directory is not readable, and consequently, Python cannot find pip distribution.

Comment: This, in combination with the fact that I had two parallell installations of python, from brew and otherwise, was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

For uninstalling pip you can use  on debian

```
sudo apt remove python-pip --purge
```

And you can install it by

for python 2.7

```
sudo apt install python2-pip
```

for python 3.x

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I suggest you to use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) by this you can create fresh env and and install the dependencies that required and easy to delete also.

Comment: This would have been great if I wasn't using mac os x :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
```

Then had to add the following to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc :)

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Type either

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Then test it by running:

```
pip
```

The instructions were listed here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-pip

Answer (score 0):

I was able to uninstall it, by installing python3.6 and then used this command

```
pip3 uninstall pip
```

if you CD into `/usr/bin` and find out pip directory,  by that you will be able to identify different versions of pip on your system

[image]

posting this in a hope, in future may someone find this helpful for uninstalling corrupt verison of pip